# Elasticsearch multiple condition query using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

There are multiple documents containing around 100 fields each. I'd like to perform a  following search trough elasticsearch Java API 5.x:

There are 3 fields I'd like to use for this search i.e.

```
department
job
name
```

I'd like to search the return documents that match fields like "department: D1", "department: D2", "job: J1", "job: J2" "name: N1"

I've been trying to do it this way

```
String[] departments = ["d1","d2","d3"];
String[] jobs = ["j1","j2","j3"];
String[] names = ["n1"];

MultiSearchRequestBuilder requestbuilder; 

requestBuilder.add(client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("department", departments)));
requestBuilder.add(client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("job", jobs)));
requestBuilder.add(client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("name", names)));

MultiSearchResponse response = requestBuilder.get();
```

However the queries are executed as if each was an individual query, i.e. in this example when j3 exists in d4, the document with d4 will be matched aswell

How to perform the search the way I mentioned? I've been trying numerous different queries and nothing seems to work, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't want to use `MultiSearchRequestBuilder`, you simply need to combine your three constraints in a `bool/filter` query:

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("department", departments))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("job", jobs))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("name", names));
SearchResponse resp = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(query).get();
```

Comment: using the code you provided I get no results at all, even tried narrowing it to only filter by departments but still the hits list is empty. if your code is correct then do you know what can possibly be the reason?

Comment: Are your fields analyzed or not? a term query is a exact match query, so your terms need to be exactly like the terms that have been indexed in the  fields you're trying to match

Comment: I had to use .setSize() in response, and it was in wrong place of the chain. it works now.

Comment: Can you confirm, if _score is working with this BoolQuery?

Comment: @SophonMen No you need to use `must()` instead of `filter()` and `matchQuery()` instead of `termsQuery()`

Comment: @SophonMen please create a new question with your requirements described

Comment: Ok, I created one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011387/spring-boot-resthighlevelclient-elastic-search-on-combine-queries

Comment: when use RestHighLevelClient we dont have prepareSearch.instead of that we can use searchSourceBuilder.query(query)

Answer (score -1):

For Elasticsearch 5.6.4 of using HighRestClient, add required number of sourcebuilder...

```
static RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
public static void multisearch() throws IOException{
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "vijay1"));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.indices("posts-1","posts-2").source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
    RestStatus status = searchResponse.status();
    System.out.println(searchResponse.toString());
```

Comment: The source builder method from SearchRequest cannot be chained, it will overwrite the given sourceBuilder each time, so only the last one will be taken into consideration.