# Spring boot RestHighLevelClient Elastic Search on combine queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, full-text-search, resthighlevelclient

I have a domain

```
 public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String description;
   private Long positionId;
  // ---- other props ------
 }
```

and I want to search for query string on field name, description and positionId
I can make it works by using **BoolQueryBuilder** but It is not working on **_score**

```
  final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
  final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("query text");
  boolQueryBuilder.filter(queryBuilder);
  boolQueryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("positionId", positionId));

  searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
 // ------- performing search -----------
```

**Noted** *This code is working but all scores are 0.0 so sorting is working*
Do you have any recommendation ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: As mentioned, you need to use `boolQueryBuilder.must()` instead of `boolQueryBuilder.filter()`

Comment: I tried, all score are 1.0