# How to search using multiple fields in Elastic Search through Java high level rest client

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, query-builder, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I'm new to Elastic search. Successfully implemented search document API for matching single field like below:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);

//Single field match, only for documentId
QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("documentId", documentId); 

SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I wanna filter data using multiple fields in single API, for Example, need to add more filters in above API as per below condition:

```
documentNumber > 66 &&  (documentCreatedDate >= date1 && documentCreatedDate <= date2) && documentName like "%test%"
```

**Can anyone please help how to apply all these filters in a single SearchRequest?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rangeQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html) as specified in docs:

```
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("documentNumber")                                             
    .gte(66);
```

```
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("documentCreatedDate")                                             
    .gte(date1)
    .lt(date2);
```

For patterns you can use wildcardQuery:

```
wildcardQuery(
        "documentName",                                              
        patternString);
```

From Docs:
Find documents where the field specified contains terms which match the pattern specified, where the pattern supports single character wildcards (?) and multi-character wildcards (*)

For applying multiple filters in single query, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440467/11537839) answer.